# Core Data configuration not on app delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I'm currently studying the Core Data Framework and I have one question about classes structure.

If I create a new project with core data all core data methods and object are in the app delegate.

Is it possibile to create a model object which manage all the core data transactions? Would it be correct?

I think that app delegate must not be too heavy, but maybe in this case is best practice to let it manage the persistence.

Any clue?

Comment: It has been done for you here ... https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create a separate class which holds all the CoreData classes and configuration. I do this for all my CoreData projects.

Comment: Do you use a singleton object for this and then use that object in all the controllers which needs data from persistence? From various tutorial the correct "pattern" to follow isn't well defined, and I'm wondering which is the cleanest way. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: There is no one perfect way of doing it. Yes I use a singleton for the CoreData class. Still some will say that singletons should not be used. Therefor all solutions are just an opinion and the "cleanest way" is just what you will find to be the cleanest way.